# Publishing failed at Deploying Stage

Tags: publishingfailed, 2013-sp1

Previously Our Deployer service was running on the Tomcat. Now we are trying to migrate it into weblogic. The new url is working fine when I am hitting it from browser but when trying to publish any item using that url I am getting the below error -

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. Unable to configure
>   processors. Unable to load Processor

Please Suggest.

Comment: Check the Deployer logs for a detailed stack trace, then please share this stack trace. To see where the log is, open your logback.xml file and look at path pointing to log storage location.

Comment: Hi Nickoli, Thanks a lot for the information. I have checked the logback.xml and found that it was failed because of an issue in custom deployer extension. Now I have resolved the issue and it is working fine.

Comment: Would be nice to understand more of the context and background story.  Maybe it would fit the format of a blog post better?